# Integral of $\int_0^\infty \frac{\sin^4(u)}{u^{k}}du$ where $k\in(1,3)$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, lebesgue-integral

My task is to

> Evaluate $$\int_0^\infty \frac{\sin^4(u)}{u^{k}}\,du$$ where $k\in(1,3).$

I've tried a few things, but nothing seems to be working. Any help?

Comment: could you rewrite the integral as $\int_0^\infty \frac{\sin^4(u)}{u^{k}}$ where $k \in(1,3)$?

Comment: Sure, I made the change

Comment: I apologize, I wasn't clear. I was asking if you've tried that

Comment: no du? anyway, IBP?

Comment: First we have to show convergence for those bounds, unless that is assumed

Comment: Looks ugly on WA for the general antiderivative... hopefully it's missing an easy solution when you are restricted to that domain. I'll take a look at it. Here's a [link](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%5Cint+%5Csin%5E4%28u%29+u%5En).

Comment: For $k \in (1,3)$ it appears convergent for all $k$... [image](http://www4f.wolframalpha.com/Calculate/MSP/MSP631222b486ea83eid513000015c6gi7390fc392a?MSPStoreType=image/gif&s=55&w=300.&h=226.&cdf=MeshControl&cdf=RangeControl)

Comment: It's convergent because the integrand is bounded in a neighborhood of $0$ and decays like $x^{-k}$ for large $x$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A chance is given by switching to Laplace transforms. We have:
$$\mathcal{L}(\sin^4 x) = \frac{24}{s \left(4+s^2\right) \left(16+s^2\right)},\qquad \mathcal{L}^{-1}\left(\frac{1}{x^k}\right)=\frac{s^{k-1}}{\Gamma(k)}$$
and the equivalent integral
$$ \frac{1}{\Gamma(k)}\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{24\, s^{k-2}}{(4+s^2)(16+s^2)}\,ds $$
can be computed through partial fraction decomposition and the residue theorem.

> Assuming $1<k<3$, we get:
>   $$ \int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{\sin^4(x)}{x^k}\,dx = \frac{\pi\, 2^k(2^k-8)}{64\,\Gamma(k)}\cdot \sec\left(\frac{\pi k}{2}\right)$$
>   and $\log(2)$ when $k=3$.

Answer (score 1):

First, write $\sin^4x=\dfrac{3-4\cos2x+\cos4x}8~.~$ Now, $3=3\cos(0~x)$, so our integral is basically  a

linear combination of terms of the form $~\displaystyle\int_0^\infty\frac{\cos(ax)}{x^k}~dx.~$ Of course, the honest reader will

immediately object that the aforementioned expression diverges for $k>1$. True indeed, but we

will [pretend to ignore](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generality_of_algebra) such issues of convergence, and evaluate the three cosine integrals *as if*

$k\in(0,1)$. How do we do that ? By using [Euler's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler's_formula) in conjunction with the well-known

integral expression for the [$\Gamma$ function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function). $($Doing that will once again stretch the norm of rigor,

since we will pretend that the upper limit, following a linear substitution involving imaginary

numbers, is real infinity, instead of complex infinity$)$. The final result will be $$a^{k-1}\cdot(-k)!~\cdot\sin\bigg(k~\dfrac\pi2\bigg),$$ where $a\in\{0,~2,~4\}.~$ Adding them all together, we have $I=\dfrac{2^k~(2^k-8)}{32}~(-k)!~\sin\bigg(k~\dfrac\pi2\bigg),~$

which can be shown to be the same as Jack's result, using Euler's [reflection formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reflection_formula) for the $\Gamma$

function. Also, for $k=2,~$ taking the limit, we have $I=\dfrac\pi4.~$ $($The expression for $\sin^4x$ was

obtained by making use of the two famous trigonometric identities for $1\pm\cos2t)$.

Comment: Nicely done Lucian. +1. You gave me a chance to look back on this gem of a question!

Answer (score 0):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[15px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$
\begin{align}
\int_{0}^{\infty}{\sin^4\pars{u} \over u^{k}}\,\dd u & \stackrel{\mrm{IBP}}{=}
{1 \over k - 1}\int_{0}^{\infty}{4\sin^{3}\pars{u}\cos\pars{u} \over
u^{k - 1}}\,\dd u =
{2 \over k - 1}\int_{0}^{\infty}{\sin^{2}\pars{u}\sin\pars{2u} \over
u^{k - 1}}\,\dd u
\\[5mm] & 
{2 \over k - 1}\int_{0}^{\infty}{\braces{\rule{0pt}{5mm}\bracks{1 - \cos\pars{2u}}/2}\sin\pars{2u} \over
u^{k - 1}}\,\dd u
\\[5mm] & =
{1 \over 2\pars{k - 1}}\int_{0}^{\infty}
{2\sin\pars{2u} - \sin\pars{4u} \over u^{k - 1}}\,\dd u
\\[5mm] & =
{1 \over k - 1}\int_{0}^{\infty}
{\sin\pars{2u} - 2u \over u^{k - 1}}\,\dd u -
{1 \over 2\pars{k - 1}}\int_{0}^{\infty}
{\sin\pars{4u} - 4u \over u^{k - 1}}\,\dd u
\\[5mm] & =
{2^{k - 2} \over k - 1}\int_{0}^{\infty}
{\sin\pars{u} - u \over u^{k - 1}}\,\dd u -
{2^{2k - 5} \over k - 1}\int_{0}^{\infty}
{\sin\pars{u} - u \over u^{k - 1}}\,\dd u
\\[5mm] & =
\bbx{{2^{k - 2} - 2^{2k - 5} \over k - 1}\int_{0}^{\infty}
{\sin\pars{u} - u \over u^{k - 1}}\,\dd u}
\\[5mm] & =
{2^{k - 2} - 2^{2k - 5} \over k - 1}\,\Im\int_{0}^{\infty}
{\expo{\ic u} - 1 - \ic u + u^{2}/2 \over u^{k - 1}}\,\dd u
\label{1}\tag{1}
\\[5mm] & =
-\,{2^{k - 2} - 2^{2k - 5} \over k - 1}\,\Im\int_{\infty}^{0}
{\expo{-y} - 1 + y - y^{2}/2 \over
y^{k - 1}\expo{\ic\pars{k - 1}\pi/2}}\,\ic\,\dd y\label{2}\tag{2}
\\[5mm] & =
-\,{2^{k - 2} - 2^{2k - 5} \over k - 1}\,
\Im\bracks{\expo{-\ic k\pi/2}\int_{0}^{\infty}y^{1 - k}\expo{-y}\,\dd y}
\\[5mm] & =
{2^{k - 2} - 2^{2k - 5} \over k - 1}\,\sin\pars{k\pi \over 2}
\Gamma\pars{2 - k} =
\pars{2^{2k - 5} - 2^{k - 2}}\,\sin\pars{k\pi \over 2}\Gamma\pars{1 - k}
\\[5mm] & =
\pars{2^{2k - 5} - 2^{k - 2}}\,\sin\pars{k\pi \over 2}
{\pi \over \Gamma\pars{k}\sin\pars{\pi k}} =
{2^{2k - 6} - 2^{k - 3} \over \Gamma\pars{k}}\,\sec\pars{k\pi \over 2}
\\[5mm] & =
\bbx{{2^{k}\pars{2^{k} - 8} \over 64\,\Gamma\pars{k}}\,\sec\pars{k\pi \over 2}}
\end{align}

> In \eqref{1} and \eqref{2}, I'll 'closed' a contour which is a quarter circle in the first quadrant. The integrals along the arc vanishes out as the arc radius $\ds{\to \infty}$.